# jQuery (IBM Worklight) page navigation and back button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, dom, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an app using IBM Worklight with jQuery libs. Structure of the app is

Login.html --> Menu.html -->

- Menu1 --> Menu1.html -->(on button click)--> Detail.html -->(save)address.html
- Menu2 --> Menu2.html -->(on button click)--> data.html --> edit.html

So the app flows as explained above. I am using jQuery single page template(in each html file) because application have lots of more pages and having all this in just on html is not suitable.

I have created

```
<div data-role="page" id="menuPage" data-theme="c"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu1" data-theme="c"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="details" data-theme="c"></div>
```

and on button click i am loading the respective html file inside respective div using `$('#divID').load(abc.html, callback)` and in `callback` creating dynamic elements in above html files and appending using `jQuery.append()`.
After elements appended i am using `$.mobile.changePage($('#menuPage'), 'pop');` to change page.

Everything working fine till now, but problem arises when i try to use back button. In chrome browser or in mobile simulator when i use back button i am able to get on the previous page, but when i try to use link/button on that previous page to go forward next page is created without any style. It's coming as in C-Grade browser without any style.

So question is that is it the right way to interact with pages and loading them in DOM. And how to get back button properly working.

Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try reading this http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf and use the sample multipage application it clearly show how to do it.

Comment: I tried using this method, but having problems in style of the page. When next page is loading no jQuery style is rendered.

Comment: Loading Jquery once in Main should work.. If could post some more detailed code it would be easy to identify issue.

Comment: Are you also passing your .css?

Comment: I have loaded the jQuery libs in the main, but style breaks. and what do you(@IdanAdar) mean by passing .css???

Comment: Any help!! I am still not able to resolve this. If you need any more clarification about question i can provide that...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ID").trigger("create") or
$("#ID").page().trigger("create") or
$("#ID").trigger("pagecreate").
```

Try adding all the above code in the call back function after loading the page one by one .